# How to find out which process is using localhost:80?

Tags: linux, port, lsof

I'm using linux mint xfce edition, my localhost:80 was used by some program but I don't which one, when I open firefox and visit localhost:80, it says

*It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.*

I've tried to use `lsof -i @localhost:80`, but it returns nothing.

Comment: `lsof -i :80` also worked, what's wrong when adding `@localhost`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`netstat -anpt | grep :80` as root user should list process using port 80.
With your web browser closed it can help you identify the process.

Comment: your message seems to be apache one

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it worked, actually it was apache2, and it was bounded to ipv6 address.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# fuser -n tcp 80
```

From the manpage:

```
-n SPACE, --namespace SPACE
      Select  a  different  name space.  The name spaces file (file names, 
      the default), udp (local UDP ports), and tcp (local TCP ports)
      are supported.  For ports, either the port number or the symbolic name can 
      be specified.  If there is no  ambiguity,  the  shortcut
      notation name/space (e.g. 80/tcp) can be used.
```

Comment: It worked, thank you, I've learned a lot from both of you.

Comment: It's sad I can only click one as the accepted answer.